# Cassava dry and chalky -- what did I do wrong?

Tags: vegetables

I bought cassava for the first time.   Chopped into about 1-inch pieces, boiled for an hour in salted water then roasted for half an hour on 350F.

It came out like pieces of chalk.  So dry and firm you had to spit it out after one bite.

I see recipes where you can boil, bake, roast, grill, fry it; from reading recipes it sounds like you can't go wrong.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: An hour is a long boil. The last time I boiled cassava prior to roasting I think it took about 15 minutes to get to the desired state, or thereabouts.

Comment: You might [edit] the question to indicate the shape and size of the chopped pieces. How firm were the pieces just before placing in the oven? Were the pieces _translucent_ after boiling?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas make that an answer, I'll upvote it (and apparently at least 3 others) and next time I'll try 15 minutes, and I'll set aside small samples to boil 30 and 60 minutes to see if that was the problem.

Comment: @AJN added piece size to question.  Don't remember their texture after boiling I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

One hour is a very long time to boil it, so perhaps that was the issue.

I've roasted cassava multiple times, and I only boil the cassava for long enough that it starts to "crack" down the middle. I cut it into round chunks then when it has boiled for 10-15 minutes it will start to split lengthways, and that's when I drain it, split it & remove the stringy core, then toss it in oil to roast. I usually roast it for about 45-55 minutes after that, but you could roast for less at a higher temperature.